# How to determine if $n (n \geq 2)$ given numbers can be summed up to a certain number?

Tags: number-theory

I'm interested in knowing if there's a theorem for checking if combinations of $n$ given positive numbers can be summed up to a certain number.

For example, if I was given $n = 2$ numbers, which are $k_1$ and $k_2$, and I was asked if I could make a combination like $n_1 * k_1 + n_2 *k_2 = C$, all $\in \mathbb{N}^+$, I could check remainders to see if it is possible.

However, if $n = 3$ or higher, how could I check if combinations of $k_1, k_2, ..., k_n$ can be summed up to a $C$?
Thank you for any inputs!

Comment: Do you require that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are positive, or can they be any integer?

Comment: Yes all numbers are positive

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is closely related to the Frobenius Coin Problem (FCP). The idea is that your $k_i$'s are denominations of coins, and we want to know which amounts we can make out of them. The difference is that the FCP requires that $n_i\ge 0$ for each $i$, while you are requiring $n_i>0$.

This difference can be reconciled as follows (using $n=3$ for illustration): The number $C$ can be formed as a positive-integer combination of $k_1, k_2, k_3$ if and only if the number $C-k_1-k_2-k_3$ can be formed as a non-negative integer combination of the same set.

For $n=2$, there is a standard result: $k_1k_2-k_1-k_2$ is the largest value that *cannot* be reached in the FCP. Therefore $k_1k_2$ is the largest number than cannot be reached using your requirement that each coin appear at least once in the sum.

For example, if $k_1=6$ and $k_2=11$, then we cannot form $C=66$ unless we allow one of the $n_i$ to be $0$, but we can get $67=2\cdot 6+5\cdot 11$, and every value over $67$.

Finding the right coefficients is straightforward enough, inductively:

Assume $C\ge 67$, and suppose $C=n_1\cdot 6+n_2\cdot 11$. If $n_2>1$, then we can form $C+1$ by subtracting $1$ from $n_2$ and adding $2$ to $n_1$. If $n_2=1$, then $n_1\ge10$, and we can then form $C+1$ by reducing $n_1$ by $9$, and increasing $n_2$ by $5$.

---

As for the values less than $66$ that can be formed, sticking with this example... there are only a few, and simply listing them is probably the easiest way to find them all. We can start with $17+11j$ for a few values of $j\ge 0$, and then $23+11j$, $29+11j$, etc.

---

For $n\ge3$, there is no similar nice formula, but there are algorithms that work. You can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: This is not quite the same as what the OP was asking about. With the Frobenius Coin Problem (FCP), the multipliers, i.e., the $k_i$ in the Wikipedia link, can be non-negative integers, while the OP requires the multipliers, i.e., the $n_i$ in the question, to all be positive. Also, the FCP only directly deals with determining the "the largest monetary amount that cannot be obtained", not how to specifically obtain, or determine you cannot obtain, any amounts smaller than it. Finally, it only directly deals with where the "coin" amounts gcd is $1$, but that is easy to accommodate.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, those are good comments, and I see that my answer can be improved. I'll probably make some edits tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Your changes make your answer much better. However, for completeness, you may wish to mention one last, potentially important, part which I stated earlier. This is that *only* values of $C$ which are an integral multiple of $\gcd(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ can be formed.

Comment: @JohnOmielan given the similar wording from different OP's, I would think there is a new programming contest going on. Most of these are entirely online, but there are more types of these than I would ever have imagined, including projects for teams of professional programmers; I was once asked to be involved with one looking for improvements in existing algorithms, using the hardware made by the sponsoring company. I was relieved when that fell through, I felt entirely out of place.